# Redeem code for in app purchases in Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have been searching how to generate redeem code for in app purchase in Android but no luck. I guess there is nothing like that. I developed an android app and I sell an item in the app. I want to give a code some users to buy the item with that code instead of paying. Is this possible ? Even if there is another ways to do ?
Thank you for replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in mechanism for what you want to achieve on Google Play; you will have to build this yourself.

You should treat the content you want to offer independently from any in-app purchases and offer an in-app purchase and code input to unlock the content.

Keep in mind you will not be able to benefit from restored purchases when a user has used a code to unlock the content. So if the user clears the data on the app, their unlocked content will be gone unless you keep a server-side record of the content the user has unlocked.